# Getting a different value while getting an image "src" with BeautifulSoup in Python than when I inspect its "src" in browser

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a website for sunglasses. I already pulled the price, brand and model values, but now I am trying to take the pictures for each sunglass, but that is irrelevant now.

When I navigate to a specific sunglass pictures webpage and inspect the src for an image, I see this value:

```
src = //img1-image.cdnsbg.com/hashImg/46e1db3236.jpg_w450h225
```

But when I use beautifulSoup to get the src for the same picture I get this value instead:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAMPDwwAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=
```

This is the webpage:

https://www.smartbuyglasses.com/designer-sunglasses/Tom-Ford/Tom-Ford-FT0248-HENRY-52A-163457.html

And here's my code to print the src value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

imageRes = requests.get("https://www.smartbuyglasses.com/designer-sunglasses/Tom-Ford/Tom-Ford-FT0248-HENRY-52A-163457.html")

imagePageSoup = soup(imageRes.text, "html.parser")
mainImgLi = imagePageSoup.find("li", "cur pro_leftIcon_click")
mainImg = mainImgLi.img["src"]

print(mainImg)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the same image? The one you're getting seems to be a gif. Possibly the page uses javascript to place images, in which case BS would not work

Comment: I believe if you do need to get dynamic content, you'll need Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the API directly, by the item `number` and get the `pic`

```
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.smartbuyglasses.com/info/itemlist/gproduct_id/32254").json()

print(r['163457']['main']['thumb'])
```

Output:

```
//img1-image.cdnsbg.com/hashImg/46e1db3236.jpg_w450h225
```

Explanation:

Photo is actually rendered via JavaScript using XHR request to the API link which I shared previously. Therefore, I've been able to locate the URL for that requests, Which can be tracked via Developer Tools for your browser and then locating the NetworkTab, then you will be able to locate it.

Comment: Good answer.Provide some more info to the user how you are getting this api? I mean `NetworkTab` etc.